# Excluding top level directory from WordPress htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

We recently changed over our website to WordPress, with the WordPress files in directory /wp/
I still want to serve other pages from other root level directories i.e., a link such as
http://www.2minuteexplainer.com/clients/xxx/some_subdir/

But any attempt to reach this directory returns a Wordpress 404 error. If I comment out the 
WordPress stuff in htaccess, the link above works as expected, but, of course, the rest of the old website shows up too.

I can't seem to find the right combination of rewrite rules.

Here is the htaccess file.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?2minuteexplainer.com$

# RewriteRule ^clients/.*$ /clients$ - [PT] 
# one of a number of workarounds I've tried in order to use this directory 

# canonical WordPress stuff follows:

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Seems like I must be making a simple mistake. But what is it??

Thx.

Comment: My hosting provider, Lunarpages, answered this for me, so I thought I'd pass it along. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move the mod_rewrite stuff ( starting with #BEGIN WordPress) into the .htaccess file that controls the WordPress install. It's /wp/ in my case.  Simple, once you know how :-)